# How to update manufacturer-customised Intel HD Graphics from a first-generation mobile Core i3?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, drivers, intel-graphics

I know my laptop is not designed for high end gaming .. obviously.. as it does not have dedicated graphics. But I am hoping that by updating to the latest Intel drivers, I might be able to squeeze out a couple of extra FPS to play older games on it at a decent frame rate (I like to revisit some of the old favourites from time to time). My graphics drivers are stuck on version 8 because Toshiba stopped providing support for my laptop (Satellite C660). I downloaded the latest Intel drivers in zip format but when trying to install these manually, I get the error shown in the screenshot in Figure 1. I am running 64-bit Windows 10 which I updated from Windows 7 when 10 came out. If anyone can provide a work-around, that would be great. 
[image: [Figure 1]]

Comment: Intel does not provide Windows 10 compatible drivers for your GPU.  Without Intel providing compatible drivers there is nothing you can do.

Comment: This does not make much sense to me. If what you are saying is the case then why should the older drivers work on Windows 10? I would have had display issues when I upgraded to Windows 10.

Comment: "why should the older drivers work on Windows 10?" - If you go to Intel's website, they don't offer Windows 10 drivers for your GPU, which is the reason I said Intel does not provide Windows 10 compatiable drivers for your GPU.  "My graphics drivers are stuck on version 8" - I am having difficulity understanding if this means you have Windows 8 drivers installed while using Windows 10 or your using the version 8 of the drivers.

Comment: Can you provide more specific model information by chance?  I asked because I am unable to find Windows 8 compatiable drivers for the i3-530, which has the Intel HD GPU, which your system is using.

Comment: Apologies. I meant that the driver version is on the latest that Toshiba provide, which is 8.15.10.2900. I have a Toshiba Satellite C660 with an i3-370M 2.4 Ghz. I have never used Windows 8. I updated this machine from Windows 7 to Windows 10.

Comment: Right;  So you can only use the generic display drivers on Windows 10.  I suggest going back to Windows 7 if want Intel display drivers in order to get better performance.   It is my believe that Windows Update is erronously attempting to install that driver, the driver itself is incompatbile, with Windows 10 hence the inability to install it.